# Sort on ID, then sort on date, then remove lines which have the older date?

Tags: sed, sorting, awk, uniq, join

I have a couple of tab delimited files.

Each file is structured like so:

```
ID          Title                                 Rating    Date_Rated
```

What I want to do is merge all these files into one, and keep only the latest rating.

file1 may have data such as:

```
70202148    Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows    5         28/12/13
```

file2 may have data such as:

```
70202148    Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows    4.5       25/12/13
```

Comment: Probably should point out, that I can do 'cat file1 file2 > joined' to merge the files; then I can do 'sort joined -k1 -n' to sort it on the ID column; but I have not figured out how to do the rest.

Comment: Are the dates always in the form `dd/mm/yy`, or might some of them be `dd/m/yy`, `d/mm/yy`, or `d/m/yy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the date field is in `dd/mm/yy` format following should do the trick:

```
cat file1 file2 ... | \
    sort -t$'\t' -n -k1,1 -k4.7r -k4.4r -k4.1r | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1n -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Using shell tools for this task would be dangerous as `sort` will not be able to understand date formats. An example is that if you run Miroslav's code in the below file the output will print the line with date record `28/02/14` which is wrong.

```
$ cat file.txt 
70202148    Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows    5         28/12/14
70202148    Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows    5         28/02/14
70202148    Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows    5         28/12/13
70202148    Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows    5         28/12/13
```

Instead of using shell tools we need to use high level scripting/programming languages for this. You can use Python, Perl, Ruby or any other language for this. Below is a `Python` script which does the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import datetime

data = {}

for line in open('file.txt'):

    line = line.strip().split()
    if len(line) == 0:
        continue

    if line[0] not in data:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line.pop(-1), '%d/%m/%y')
        data[line.pop(0)] = {'rating':line.pop(-1), 'year':date, 'title': ' '.join(line[1:]) }
    else:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line.pop(-1), '%d/%m/%y')
        if date > data[line[0]]['year']:
            data[line.pop(0)] = {'rating':line.pop(-1), 'year':date, 'title': ' '.join(line[1:]) }


for val in sorted(data):
    print('{} {} {} {}'.format(val, data[val]['title'], data[val]['rating'], data[val]['year'].strftime('%d/%m/%y')))
```

***Output:***

```
$ ./filter.py 
70080038 Iron Man 4 18/02/14
70202148 Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows 5 28/12/14
```

Comment: I agree on using Python is generally better choice since it's more flexible and all. Nevertheless, I'm not sure you've noticed fields are tab separated. If you account for that you will see above `sort` will work just fine with some constraints (e.g., fixed date format), also it doesn't care much about possibility of having multiple rows with same dates (make sort stable could be one approach).